# Error creating Session: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found

Tags: java

using Jboss 7.1.1. I have connection to the DB out of localhost:9990/console.
The Connection Test is correct. But when i try to put something into the DB an exception occurs:

```
Error creating Session: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property   name="hibernate.connection.url">
     jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

     <mapping resource="MyApp/WebApp/model/Member.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

My Session factory:

```
static
{
    try
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
    catch (HibernateException he)
    {
        System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
```

inside JBOSSHOME/modules/com/mysql/main are the module.xml and the connector.
i dont need to have the connector inside the WEB-INFlib folder..or do I?

any ideas??

Ok ..i found a solution. I putted the connector jar in JBOSSHOME/modules/org/hibernate/main and changed the module.xml...i dont know why that works..but it works!!

Comment: You need to have the mysql connector jar in your lib folder unless `JBOSSHOME/modules/com/mysql/main` is on your application classpath. It seems it isn't.

Comment: but i tested the connection out of the console...it works

Comment: What does your connection test look like? What does it do?

Comment: Successfully created JDBC Connection..Successfully connected to database test thats what it says

Comment: I meant show us the code that connects to the database.

Comment: there is no code..its out of localhost:9990/console..its a jboss tool with this tool you create the connection to db and it writes automatically into standalone.xml

Comment: So you have 2 applications? JBoss and your own? JBoss is probably running with the correct classpath that contains the jar. But your application is running without it.

Comment: but the connection url are the same??

Comment: It has nothing to do with the url. Your application is looking for the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` but it can't find it because it isn't in the classpath.

Comment: if i put it in the classpath the application wont find it either..i tried it

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got from Hibernate

`Error creating Session: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found`

occurs because the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is missing from your classpath, ie. the jar containing it should be in `WEB-INF/lib`. Add the mysql connector jar to that folder.

Comment: what do you think..i tried it ..put it into WEB-INF/lib added into build path but same exemption

Comment: You need to give us some more details about your application structure.

Comment: ok i use jboss 7.1.1 as mentioned. im try to use jconnector out of my jbosshome/modules/com/mysql/main Folder. I got one Member class with some attributes and a hibernate.cfg.xml. The driver class i did is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. But im not shure if this has to change when i want to use the connector out of jboss

Answer (score 0):

Inside my domain.xml (or standalone.xml) I have this:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/Datasource" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName</connection-url>
    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>name</user-name>
        <password>pass</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="com.mysql"module="com.mysql">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

inside the tag:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
```

Comment: <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/test" pool-name="test" jta="false" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.mysql.main</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>

Comment: can i see you hibernate.cfg.xml?Because the driver-class is missing in your standalone.xml